# missing context in coffeescript => operator

Tags: coffeescript

```
    App.WebNotificationComponent = Em.Component.extend
      subscriptionQueue: null

      connection: (->
        App.StompConnection.create(subscriptionQueue: @get('subscriptionQueue'))
      ).property('subscriptionQueue')

      willDestroy: ->
        @get('connection').destroy()

    App.AlertsIndexAlertWebNotificationComponent = App.WebNotificationComponent.extend
      subscriptionQueue: "notifications"

      didInsertElement: ->
        @get('connection').onMessage = ((message) ->
          result = JSON.parse(message.body)
          App.AlertNotification.store.find('alert_notification', result.id).then (notification) =>
            debugger
        ).bind(@get('targetObject'))
        @get('connection').connect()
```

At the debugger breakpoint, I am no longer able to access **message** or **result**.

Is there anything that I am doing wrong or another way to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

You can't access those values in the debugger because you didn't close over them, so they're not available in the closure. If you use them in the closure, they'll be available. Javascript has to know that you're going to use a variable in order to save it in the closed scope.

In other words, this will work as expected:

```
result = JSON.parse(message.body)
    App.AlertNotification.store.find('alert_notification', result.id).then (notification) =>
        console.log(message)
        console.log(result)
```